# VScode: SFTP extension: Edit file only update file on local system but not updating on remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

VScode:
SFTP extension: SFTP (natizyskunk )
I made sftp connection to remote.
and when i open a remote file and edit something and save.
that save update file in local
but not updating on remote server.
but if manually do "upload" then works.

many things, but no success

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can connect to SFTP and open VS Code folder at something like `/run/user/1000/gvfs/*`